# Transfer Function: Trying to understand the Laplace analysis of this circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, transfer-function, laplace-transform

I am trying to do the transfer function of this circuit and also trying to understand the frequency domain thing of the Laplace transform.

[image]

I want to do a transfer function of VA/V1, considering B to be ground.

After doing the node analysis and if my equations are correct, I have ended with this transfer function on the s domain.

[image]

A calculator online gave these answers for the cubic equation on the denominator

```
x1 = -915.52763
x2 = -42.23618 + i * 3304.67537
x3 = -42.23618 - i * 3304.67537
```

These are my problems:

1. what do these numbers represent?
2. the equation is on the denominator, what about the s100 on the nominator?
3. how do I find the frequency performance of this circuit as the frequency changes?
4. what does this function say about the circuit?

Comment: There is something strange in your transfer function (TF): 1) you have two energy-storing elements so \$D(s)\$ the denominator should be of order 2 not 3 2) for \$s = 0\$, in dc, your TF should simplify to a resistive divider involving \$R_2\$ and \$R_1\$. Finally, there is no zero meaning \$N(s)\$ should be 1. The correct result should be in the form of \$H(s)=H_0\frac{1}{1+b_1s+b_2s^2}\$ with \$H_0=\frac{R_2}{R_1+R_2}\$. Let me know if you want me to derive this TF as a formal response, it is easy with the fast analytical techniques or FACTs.

Comment: please do it... FACT? I will check the equations.

Comment: The DC gain of your TF is zero, which is clearly wrong (should be 10/11 = 0.91)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May I suggest that you start by simplifying the 2 resistors into one resistor. I'm suggesting this because it makes the math a lot easier and I think you have a mistake in your final formula. So, the voltage source reduces from 10 volts to 9.09 volts in series with a resistance of 90.90 ohms due to standard circuit theorums.

This then has a standard formula: -

$$H(s) = \dfrac{\omega_n^2}{s^2 +2\zeta\omega_n s+ \omega_n^2}$$
Where \$\omega_n = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{LC}}\$

And \$\zeta= \dfrac{R}{2}\sqrt{\dfrac{C}{L}}\$

The value for R is the newly recalculated value of 90.9 ohms. To offer a little more help, \$\omega_n\$ is the natural resonant frequency of the filter and \$\zeta\$ is called the damping ratio (also equal to the reciprocal of 2Q).

Now if you want to see what this looks like you can [use this on-line calculator](http://www.stades.co.uk/RLC%20filters/RLC%20LPF.html) and plug-in the values: -

[image]

Resonance occurs at about 503 Hz and there is a peak in the response of about 11 dB. Circuit Q is about 3.5.

But don't forget that there is an overall attenuation (due to me simplying the two resistors into one resistor) so the formulas are multiplied by 0.909.

I haven't used your equations because I can see that there is an error in the final formula you derived.

Comment: Your answer is 100 light-years ahead of me. Let me take some time to digest it.

Comment: B R I L L I A N T! The problem here is that I was not seeing the simplification, probably because my eye is not trained enough but I did two source transformations involving V1, R1 and R2 and saw that the whole thing could be replaced by a voltage source of 9,09V in series with a 90,90 resistor. BRILLIANT

Comment: Well you didn't take as much time as I thought so kudos to you!

Comment: Hi, if you don't mind I have 3 little questions about your answer. I have verified the equations and found this one for the gain: F(s) = 10^7(s^2 + 90.9s + 10^7). When I plug that on my graph app I get resonance at around 2kHz, not 503Hz as you. The second thing is this: what is the meaning of that peak? Is it the output bigger than the input? The third thing is this: we are doing the whole thing using R=90.90. Do I have to correct the values in 10%? I mean, if this is the R equivalent, isn't it equivalent? I am under the impression that you implied that. Thanks.

Comment: I mean 10^7/(s^2 + 90.9s + 10^7)

Comment: 10^7 = 10,000,000 and the square root of that is 3162 radians per second or 503 Hz. Also Fres = \$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{LC}}\$ = 3162 radians per second. I don't know how your app disagrees. The peak does actually mean voltage amplification. If you input a sinewave at 1 volt at about 500 Hz you will get an output that is nearly 4 times bigger in amplitude. But, the final amplitude will be 90.9% of what my graph shows because of the two resistors.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to determine this transfer function is to use the fast analytical circuits techniques or [FACTs](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1119236371). In these techniques, you consider the circuit in different conditions to determine its time constants. This will lead you to a so-called *low-entropy* format in which you should see gain, poles and zeros if any.

With your circuit, you have two energy-storing elements: a capacitor \$C_1\$ and an inductor \$L_2\$. As they have independent state variables, this is a 2nd-order circuit. As such, the denominator \$D(s)\$ must obey the following expression: \$D(s)=1+b_1s+b_2s^2\$. From this expression, you can rework it and put it under the canonical form \$D(s)=1+\frac{s}{\omega_0Q}+(\frac{s}{\omega_0})^2\$.

We start with \$s=0\$. Redraw your circuit in which the inductor is replaced by a short circuit (its impedance is \$sL_2\$ which reduces to 0) while the capacitor is open-circuited (its impedance is \$\frac{1}{sC_1}\$ and is infinite at dc). The circuit looks likes this:

[image]

In dc, the gain \$H_0\$ is a simple resistive divider: \$H_0=\frac{R_2}{R_1+R_2}\$. Now, reduce the excitation source to 0 V: replace \$V_{in}\$ by a short circuit and "look" through the connecting terminals of \$L_2\$ and \$C_1\$ while the second element is put in its dc state (open-circuited cap and shorted inductor). In the first case, for \$\tau_1\$ you "see" \$R_1||R_2\$ which implies a time constant equal to \$\tau_1=C_1(R_1||R_2)\$. Do the same for \$\tau_2\$ involving \$L_2\$ and you see an infinite resistance leading to a 0-s time constant. Now, set the capacitor in its high-frequency state (a short circuit) and "see" the resistance offered by \$L_2\$'s terminals in this mode: \$\tau_{12}=\frac{L_2}{R_1||R_2}\$. You can now calculate \$D(s)=1+s(\tau_1+\tau_2)+s^2\tau_1\tau_{12}\$ and rewrite it into the canonical form given below:

[image]

Now, you can determine the same expression using the classical brute-force approach with a Thévenin-equivalent model. Nothing wrong here but a) it is likely to be a complicated exercise b) you may make mistakes - I would : ) and c) you will have to inject more energy to get the canonical form I gave. With this form, you have the resonant frequency \f_0\$ set to 503.3 Hz, a dc gain of -0.83 dB and a peaking of 10.8 dB. This is what the below shot confirms:

[image]

The FACTs have lead you there straight away to the compact form you need without writing a single line of algebra, just going through simple sketches that you inspect. If you made a mistake, just fix the guilty drawing and update the time constant. If you are solving transfer functions whether you have passive or active sources, the FACTs cannot be beaten!

Comment: it will take me a while to digest what you have said. I will comment here when I do. Your answer is amazing!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: you lost me here... "Do the same for τ2 involving L2 and you see an infinite resistance leading to a 0-s time constant." What is exactly tau?

Comment: \$\tau\$ is the time constant associated with the energy-storing element: \$RC\$ for a capacitor and \$\frac{L}{R}\$ for an inductor. The term \$R\$ is what you need to determine by inspection, when "looking" through the component connections. Have a look at this PPT for an introduction to the FACTs: http://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/PPTs/Chris%20Basso%20APEC%20seminar%202016.pdf